# Calculating the Weighted Average Cost of inventoy log

Tags: sql-server, average, weighted

I have to calculate my products stock cost, so for every product after each buy, i have to recalculate the Weighted Average Cost.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fqfmh.png)

I got a view thats bring me the current product's stock after each in/out:

StockID ArticleID   TranDate    TranCode    Items   Price     WACPrice  WACRunningTotal
62515   698         00:00,0       IN        484,05   280,56              484,05
89010   698         11:48,1       OUT       4                            480,05
90155   698         39:26,8       OUT       3                            477,05
93300   698         32:21,5       IN        400      302,1               877,05
89202   698         04:57,4       OUT       1,5                          875,55
87474   698         05:28,6       OUT       4                            871,55

I want to  calculate WACPrice field

```html
create proc sp_GetInventoryDetails_ByWAC
-- sp_GetInventoryDetails_ByWAC 10017
@ArticleId int
as
begin

-- select * from #stocktemp order by trandate 
--select *, 0 as WACRunningTotal into #StockTemp from stock where articleid=10000 order by TranDate;
;WITH y AS 
(
  SELECT articleid,TranDate,trancode, items, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TranDate)
    FROM stock where ArticleID =@ArticleId
), x AS
(
    SELECT articleid, TranDate,trancode, rn, items, rt = items
      FROM y
      WHERE rn = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT y.articleid,y.TranDate,y.trancode, y.rn, y.items,case when y.TranCode not in (1,5,6,10,20) then x.rt - y.items else x.rt+y.Items end
      FROM x INNER JOIN y
      ON y.rn = x.rn + 1
)

update st set st.WACRunningTotal=x.rt
from stock st
inner join x on x.ArticleID=st.ArticleID and x.TranDate=st.TranDate and x.TranCode=st.TranCode and isnull(st.WACRunningTotal,0)=0

OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);




;WITH    StockCTE
          AS (SELECT    articleid,
                        items,
                        WACRunningTotal,
                        WACPrice,
                        trandate,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY articleid ORDER BY trandate) RowNum
              FROM      stock where ArticleID =@ArticleId),

/* CleanStock - A recursive CTE. This runs down the list of values for each stock, checking the Price column, if it is null it gets the previous non NULL value.*/
        CleanStock
          AS (SELECT    articleid,
                        items,
                        WACRunningTotal,
                        ISNULL(WACPrice ,0) WACPrice ,/* Ensure we start with no NULL values for each stock */
                        trandate,
                        RowNum
              FROM      StockCTE cur
              WHERE     RowNum = 1
              UNION ALL
              SELECT    Curr.articleid,
                        curr.items,
                        Curr.WACRunningTotal,
                        case when Curr.WACPrice=0 then  prev.WACPrice else ((curr.WACPrice*curr.Items)+(prev.WACRunningTotal*prev.WACPrice))/curr.WACRunningTotal end as WACPrice,
                        Curr.trandate,
                        Curr.RowNum
              FROM      StockCTE curr
              INNER JOIN CleanStock prev ON curr.articleid = prev.articleid
                                           AND curr.RowNum = prev.RowNum + 1)

/* Update the base table using the result set from the recursive CTE */
    UPDATE trg
    SET trg.WACPrice = src.WACPrice
    FROM    stock trg
    INNER JOIN CleanStock src ON trg.articleid = src.articleid
                                AND trg.trandate = src.trandate and trg.ArticleID=@ArticleId 

/* Display the results */
SELECT * FROM stock where ArticleID=@ArticleId order by TranDate

--drop table stock



end
```

when i implement THIS  code i receive the following error :

"Msg 240, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_GetInventoryDetails_ByWAC, Line 9 [Batch Start Line 0] Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column "rt" of recursive query "x"." please help

Comment: Could you add some tags to indicate the technology? I guess it is SQL. Any specific flavor?

Comment: yes it is sql (SGBD : Sql server)

Comment: so, if you add a tag, like the ones you did (`average` and `weighted`). SQL Server experts will be notified of your question